# Is this a correct grammar for untyped lambda calculus?

Tags: formal-grammars, lambda-calculus, parsers

I am trying to write a recursive-descent parser for untyped lambda calculus. While researching the way of formulating the grammar, I managed to put together something like this:

```
without left-recursion:
TERM         -> APPLICATION | ABSTRACTION
ABSTRACTION  -> LAMBDA LCID DOT TERM
APPLICATION  -> ATOM APPLICATION'
APPLICATION' -> ATOM APPLICATION' | ε       
ATOM         -> LPAREN TERM RPAREN | LCID
LCID         -> 'a' | 'b' | ... | 'z'
DOT          -> '.'
LAMBDA       -> 'λ'
```

I assume that for writing the parser I do not necessarily need the productions that only expand into terminals.

Can this grammar be used to write a recursive descent parser that only does 1-token lookups? What would be the resulting AST for `(λx.x)(λy.y)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your grammar looks fine. You can make a recursive descent parser for it.

The AST for `(\x.x)(\y.y)` is, if I got everything right,

```
term
  application
    atom
      lparen
      term
        abstraction
          lambda
          lcid
            x
          dot
          term
            application
              atom
                lcid
                  x
              application'
                eps
      rparen
    application'
      atom
        lparen
        term
          abstraction
            lambda
            lcid
              x
            dot
            term
              application
                atom
                  lcid
                    y
                application'
                  eps
        rparen
      application'
        eps
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. The reason I asked for the parse tree is because I'm having trouble understanding how a parser would determine that the outermost TERM expands into APPLICATION. Is this possible to do using 1-token lookup?

Comment: @JanParzydło TERM expands into either APPLICATION or ABSTRACTION. Only the latter begins with LAMBDA. So, if you see LPAREN, you try APPLICATION.